# Improve concurrency on a simple AJAX call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, node.js

I have created a simple ajax call with the following code:

**controller.rb**

```
def locations
    sleep 1.2
    some_data = [{"name"=> "chris", "age"=> "14"}]
    render json: some_data
end
```

**view.js**

```
function getLocation() {
     $.get('/location').success(function(data){console.log(data);});
}

$(".button").click(function() {getLocation();});
```

**Routes.rb**

```
get '/location' => 'controller#locations'
```

Note that the `sleep 1.2` in the controller it is to prevent doing background jobs or database calls.

The screenshot below is from the devtools Network tab, it shows I have clicked the button 8 times and all the subsequent calls are stalled until the previous action is finished. I think it is due to Rails being single threaded? Will it be a different case if the server is made with NodeJS? And How can I achieve similar concurrency with Rails for similar AJAX calls?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would argue that a sleep in a controller is a very bad idea and allows to run Denial of Service attckas against your server. Beside that, most application servers can be configured in a way that allows concurrency. What server do you use in production?

Comment: Hi @spickermann it is a development server and I am using webrick

Comment: Webrick allows only one request at a time, that is true. This is a problem you will not face with production with a "production-ready" server (see @Oxynum answer). You r focus should be to remove the `sleep` call from your controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not due to Rails, but to the Rails server you are using. Some are single threaded, and others can be launched as multithreaded.
For instance, if you use Phusion passenger, you can configure it to run using several threads and so to improve the concurrency. You should look for Rails "server" comparisons instead of trying to find a solution or a problem with the Rails "framework".

Popular servers are Thin, Unicorn, Puma, Phusion passenger. The default development server is call Webrick.

There are a lot of other stackoverflow questions relating to the differences between servers so I think you should look into them.

Comment: With some study heroku suggested puma as the web server for concurrency. Any recommendation on threads to understand more about configuring puma server ?

Comment: Try that post from heroku to understand how it works : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections